# $[\nu_4,\iota_4]=?$, $\nu_4$ is the Hopf map in $\pi_7(S^4)$ and $\iota_4$ is the generator of $\pi_4(S^4)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$[\nu_4,\iota_4]=?$, where $\nu_4$ is the Hopf map in $\pi_7(S^4)$ and $\iota_4$ is the generator of $\pi_4(S^4)$ which represents the identity map, $[-,-]$ is the Whitehead product.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: Ravanel's book is available on-line.  Have you looked there? 

Answer (score 3):

This is how far I can get without checking a book.

Since $v_4 = \pm {1\over 2} [i_4, i_4]$, you are interested in the triple Whitehead product
$\alpha = {1\over 2}[ [i_4, i_4],i_4]$.  Since it is a Whitehead product, its suspension is
trivial. 
The Jacobi identity for Whitehead products shows that $[ [i_4, i_4],i_4]$ has order $3$;
so $\alpha$ has order either $3$ or $6$.

Comment: $2\nu_4-E\omega=\pm[i_4,i_4]$,so,what is $[E\omega,i_4]?$

Comment: where $\omega$ is the generator of $\pi_6(S^3)=\textbf{Z}_{12}$, and $E$ is the suspension.